# Object constructor has method to create input

Tags: javascript

here is demo:

[http://jsfiddle.net/b772ubch/e](http://jsfiddle.net/b772ubch/)

As you can see, i have four inputs, when i put values, in console i can check for example amount of calories ( calcCalories(); ).

```
enter code here
```

What do i want to do?
I want to add a method to object constructor, which adds text input automatically to body section during adding new Product, and this input has to be a siblling of previous input.  Any Idea?

Comment: Please edit question and post (relevant) part of your code in the question (with proper formatting). Links eventually die... so the question becomes useless, and the sole point here it that question keep some values in the future, not only for OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be creating label fields for you inputs. What I did is updated your `createInput` function to accept the product name. It then handles all the work of creating a label, input, and br. It fills in the innerHTML for the label. You were on the right track.
http://jsfiddle.net/b772ubch/4/

## JS

```
function createInput(name) {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  var newlabel = document.createElement("Label");


  input.type = "text";
  input.className = "css-class-name";
  input.setAttribute("id", name);
  
  newlabel.setAttribute("for", name);
  newlabel.innerHTML = "Amount of " + name + " [g]: ";
  
  container.appendChild(newlabel);
  container.appendChild(input);
  container.appendChild(br);
  return input;
}

// Constructor //

function Product(name, calories, protein, fat, carbohydrates) {
  this.name = name;
  this.calories = calories;
  this.protein = protein;
  this.fat = fat;
  this.carbohydrates = carbohydrates;

  createInput(this.name);

}
```

Comment: works fine, i only corrected  newlabel.innerHTML = "Amount of " + name + " [g]: ";  , I removed key word this.